# Conda search can't find package that can be found on conda cloud

Tags: python, conda, anaconda3

For example, I can find [`gxx_linux-64`](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gxx_linux-64) on anaconda cloud, but when I search for it using `conda search`:

```
conda search -c conda-forge gxx_linux-64
```

It tells me

```
Loading channels: done
No match found for: gxx_linux-64. Search: *gxx_linux-64*

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - gxx_linux-64

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conda restricts searching to the `noarch` and the platform-specific subdirectories of channels. In this case, the channel information indicates that the search is run on **osx-64** platform, whereas the package is clearly a **linux-64** build, hence why it isn't found.

One can specifically search other subdirectories by including this is the channel specification. That is, no matter the platform from which ones searches, the package should be found with

```bash
conda search -c conda-forge/linux-64 gxx_linux-64
```

or, using the full MatchSpec syntax

```bash
conda search conda-forge::gxx_linux-64[subdir=“linux-64”]
```

However, note that this package won't be compatible with **osx-64**.